# Try to disabled input after ajaxsubmit () mvc 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, disabled-input

i works with MVC 4, and i try to submit form with ajaxsumbit, and it works! but now, after sumbit form with ajaxsubit i want to disabled some input's:

Controller:

```
//
    // POST: /Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(DadosComerciais dados)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.DadosComerciais.Add(dados);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(dados);
    }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Contrato", FormMethod.Post, new { id="formContrato"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Série: </td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("Serie", new List<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "form-control input-sm", onchange = "NumDocContrato(this)"})
        </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

}

And the js file:

```
function saveContrato()
{
//Guardar os dados comerciais para os contratos
//$("#formContrato").submit();
$("#formContrato").ajaxSubmit({
    type: "post",
    url: $("#formContrato").attr("action"),
    clearForm: false,
    success: 
        $("#Serie").prop("disabled", "disabled")
});

$("#formContrato").submit(function () {
    return false;
});
$("#DefinirEstab").attr("onclick", "CountEstab()");
```

`}`

Answer (score 0):

Assign the `Serie` ID to your dropdown first.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Serie", new List<SelectListItem>(), new { id = "Serie", @class = "form-control input-sm", onchange = "NumDocContrato(this)"})
```

Change :

```
$("#Serie").prop("disabled", "disabled")
```

To:

```
success: function () {
    $("#Serie").prop("disabled", true)
   }
```

Comment: already tried and does not work.
also already tried with:
 `$("#Serie").attr("disabled", true)`

Comment: are you trying to disable the dropdown?

Comment: dont work. your answer makes the dropdown disabled but does not save in the database

Comment: yes i did.
`@Html.DropDownList("Serie", new List<SelectListItem>(), new {@class = "form-control input-sm",  id="Serie", onchange = "NumDocContrato(this)"})`

`    $("#formContrato").ajaxSubmit({
        type: "post",
        url: $("#formContrato").attr("action"),
        clearForm: false,
        success: 
            $("#Serie").prop("disabled", true)
    });`

Comment: I dont know if this would work but try wrapping the  `$("#Serie").prop("disabled", true)` in a function. Check my edit.